# dotnetnuke + angular routeprovider

Tags: angularjs, dotnetnuke

My team and I are developing a muli-page MVC application using AngularJS and DotNetNuke. In our routes.js, we point to specific controllers and templates.

Here is our routes.js code:

```
angular.module('SurveyWrangler').config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('', {
        redirectTo: '/surveys'
    })

    .when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/surveys'
    })

    .when('#', {
        redirectTo: '/surveys'
    })

.when('/surveys', {
    controller: "SurveyIndexController",
    templateUrl: "/DesktopModules/HealthPlanSurvey/templates/survey/index.html"
})

.when('/surveys/new', {
    templateUrl: "/DesktopModules/HealthPlanSurvey/templates/survey/create.html",
    controller: "SurveyCreateController"
})

.when('/surveys/:id', {
    templateUrl: "/DesktopModules/HealthPlanSurvey/templates/survey/show.html",
    controller: "SurveyShowController"
})

.when('/surveys/:id/edit', {
    templateUrl: "/DesktopModules/HealthPlanSurvey/templates/survey/edit.html",
    controller: "SurveyEditController"
})

.when('/surveys/:id/carryforward', {
    templateUrl: "/DesktopModules/HealthPlanSurvey/templates/survey/carryForward.html",
    controller: "SurveyCarryForwardController"
})
});
```

**The link for the app is** `www.OURWEBSITE.com/Surveys#/surveys`**, but the URL changes to just** `~/Surveys#` **when you click the link in the menu bar**.

The menu bar is rendered out by DNN. This is baffling to me because from what I can tell from the code, I should be redirected back to `~/Survey#/surveys`. Instead, I get a blank screen. Also, *no errors in the browser console*.

Thanks for any help!